# How to use sed against specific line in a file

Tags: linux, grep

There are two instances of a word `music` in a file.

```
Hello music
Goodbye music
```

If I were to use sed to replace an instance of `music` only where `grep Hello` is applied, what would I need to add to a `sed` comand?

Currently `sed -i -e "s/$olmusic/$newmusic/g" file.txt` replaces every instance of $oldmusic in a file but I need it to replace only the one where condition of `grep` is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
sed -i "/Hello/{s/$olmusic/$newmusic/}" file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` offers to use a regex as an [address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html):

```
sed -i -e "/Hello/s/$olmusic/$newmusic/" file.txt
```